# How to remove stains from a white dirty car?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I wanted to "clean" a car using Photoshop but Healing tool etc. don't work good enough to remove the dirt.

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Lasso Tool** to make partial selections areas and go to menu **Filter** → **Noise** → **Dust and Scratches...** or **Filter** → **Noise** → **Median**

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

With adjusted Levels and Median:

[image]

Comment: ...I always thought 'Dust and Scratches' was there to *add* said elements rather than remove them. +1!

Comment: The only one option to "add" is Add noise. Despeckle, Dust & Scratches, Median and Reduce Noise are to remove in different levels. Dust & Scratches is perfect for photo negative scratches. For this question I think Median fits better.

Comment: Good use of "dust and scratches". I normally only think if it being dust and scratches on a negative scan, not a car! haha. I might try it on self-portraits in the future!

Comment: Is the OP aware that this only changes the image? The physical will stay as dirty as before. I'm in CS6 right now - maybe it's fixed in CC :-)

Comment: I fixed it using shadow/highlights and a lot of color correction, it made the job.